# Extract response when response contain only a single value

Tags: performance, testing, loadrunner

How to extract the response in Load Runner when there is only one value in response.

For example response contains value "3".I need this value in next request.How can I correlate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where there is no other data returned in the message body, you can use empty left and right boundaries to capture everything that is returned. You will of course need to do some validation on the returned value.

```
  web_reg_save_param_ex(
        "ParamName=cValue", 
        "LB=",
        "RB=",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=body",
        LAST);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been described by Joel, you can also try this:

```
Snapshot View --> HTTP Data --> Response Body --> Select the response value to be correlated --> Right click --> Create Correlation
```

This would create the correlation code automatically on to the script at the required place.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a left and right boundary for you to hook to, example

```
..."lb=<html>","rb=</html>",...
```

What did you try before asking and what were the results of those experiments?

Comment: There is no other values.Means no boundaries are there.That is the reason why I posted the question.I need to capture that particular value. I dont know any way to capture a value without boundaries.

Comment: Whether your response is XML or HTML, there are qualified headers and footers for both valid and invalid responses.   Turn up your log level to view the full response and you will find that you have something that you can grab a hold of in terms of header and footer, even if at the page level.

Comment: @JamesPulley Unfortunately not everyone adheres to web standards these days, and while there are perfectly lightweight messaging formats like JSON, we still come across the occasional raw responses like Aajan was speaking of.

Comment: web_reg_save_param("tsphp_example","LB=","RB=\n","Search=Body",LAST);